# Drilldown on label in spiderweb graph

Tags: highcharts

With Highcharts it is possible to drilldown, for example on a column chart.
However, I have a [spiderweb graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider) where I need to drilldown. As an alternative, a drilldown on the label text would also be acceptable.

Is it possible to create this drilldown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, drilldown module is working with polar charts.

If you add *highcharts-more* lib and set [`polar`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.polar) to `true` in a [column with drilldown chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown), then drilldown will work on columns as well as on *xAxis* labels and *dataLabels* in spiderweb graph.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lgode0/

Comment: Thanks, this is something I can work with. So basically you always would create a column chart and then "disguise" it as a spiderweb instead of creating a spiderweb directly?

Comment: Yes. Spiderweb is created in Highcharts through changing from a [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) to a [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) via setting API's option [`polar`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.polar) to true.